# Bayesian Beta regresion usign BetaBayes in R

Tags: r, bayesian

I am running a Bayesian Beta regression using the R package `betaBayes` is it possible to add a shrinkage prior such as the 'horseshoe' prior. I see in the package documentation the ability to give the support for the prior but I am not quite sure how to code a shrinkage prior to help with feature selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can specify a shrinkage prior in the `betaBayes` package.

One alternative is to use the [`stan_betareg`](https://mc-stan.org/rstanarm/reference/stan_betareg.html) function from the `rstanarm` package which does Bayesian beta regression using an MCMC engine and [supports hierarchical shrinkage priors](https://mc-stan.org/rstanarm/reference/priors.html#hierarchical-shrinkage-family) out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, that was my first choice but I am having trouble installing  the packge on my system. I guess I'll put my full effort there.